# JGroup 3.2.7 not performing a cluster when hosts are distributed

Tags: java, protocols, multicast, jgroups

JGroup version : 3.2.7-final

1.) On same machine two instances of Demo Program

`java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true org.jgroups.demos.Draw`

WORKING FINE.

2.) On two different machines in same subnet - Demo Program

`java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true org.jgroups.demos.Draw`

also tried

`java -cp $CLASSPATH -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djgroups.udp.mcast_addr=239.192.0.1 -Djgroups.udp.mcast_port=45590 -Djgroups.udp.ip_ttl=32 org.jgroups.demos.Draw`

NONE OF ABOVE WORKING. I can not see any incoming request from the remote host.

But when I try java org.jgroups.tests.McastReceiverTest and java org.jgroups.tests.McastSenderTest in two machine seems that working.

But no luck with the replication setup.

Note : One of my cluster machine 32 bit while other one is 64 bit.

Appreciate your help to resolve this issue.

Comment: What's your bind_address? Have you tried to change it? e.g something like [this](http://jgroups.1086181.n5.nabble.com/Getting-jgroups-to-bind-on-all-interfaces-td4749.html)

Comment: Thanks. I tried with IP (10.30.1.62) for bind_address but did not work. I'll try the options in the thread and will update you.

Comment: It started to work after specifying -Djgroups.bind_addr=x.x.x.x I assume it's optional to specify bind_addr for UDP. What's configuration wrong with my cluster machines ?

Comment: @era, you need to bind to a correct local IP address if you have many network interfaces running on that machine. For example: if your jgroups network is using a WIFI network, you need to bind to an IP address that uses that network (via its WIFI network interface).